# Mobile menu not showing up only on Iphones

Tags: html, css, ios, sass

I have a fixed bottom mobile navigation in my website. When you click the hamburger Icon it calls the left navigation div with JS by increasing the width.

Everything is fine in any kind of mobile phones but in IPhones I dont even see the bottom fixed navigation bar. There is a code overflow-x:hidden and this makes the left tabbed content to be hide so until you press the hamburger icon you dont see the left tabbed menu. When I delete this code the menu show ups in Iphones but it looks terrible because I see a part of left menu. How can I fix this? please check the photo and you will see.

https://codepen.io/ouz-kaan-yataan/pen/jOWWOzo

here is the live example so if you open this link with your Iphone you wont see the mobile bottom fixed navbar. But any other device will show it. And you can resize your browser windows so you will see the navbar.

[Details with Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S7Qst.png)

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">





    <!-- MOBİL MENÜ İÇ TABLAR BAŞLANGIÇ -->


    <div class="page-border"></div>

        <div class="tabs"><!--tablar başlangıç-->


            <nav class="tabs-nav">

                <ul>
                    <li style="border-right:1px solid #554545;" data-tab="1">
                    <img class="mobilmenuicikonlar" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/sporlar.png" 
                    border="0" alt=""/><a class="nav-link" href="#">Spor</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border-right:1px solid #554545;" data-tab="2">
                    <img class="mobilmenuicikonlar" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/canli.png" 
                    border="0" alt=""/><a class="nav-link" href="#">Canlı</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="" data-tab="3">
                    <img class="mobilmenuicikonlar" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/casino.png" 
                    border="0" alt=""/><a class="nav-link" href="#">Casino</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border-right:1px solid #554545; border-top:1px solid #554545;" data-tab="4">
                    <img class="mobilmenuicikonlar" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/canlicasino.png" 
                    border="0" alt=""/><a class="nav-link" href="#">Canlı Casino</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border-right:1px solid #554545; border-top:1px solid #554545;" data-tab="5">
                    <img class="mobilmenuicikonlar" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/poker.png" 
                    border="0" alt=""/><a class="nav-link" href="#">Poker</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="border-top:1px solid #554545;" data-tab="6">
                    <img class="mobilmenuicikonlar" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/promosyonlar.png" 
                    border="0" alt=""/><a class="nav-link" href="#">Promosyonlar</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav> 

            <div class="tab-container"><!--tab container başlangıç-->

                <div class="tab-content" data-tab="1"><!--tab içerik başlangıç-->

                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 1. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 1. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 1. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 1. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 1. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 1. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>


                </div><!--tab içerik bitiş-->

                <div class="tab-content" data-tab="2"><!--tab içerik başlangıç-->

                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 2. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 2. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 2. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 2. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 2. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 2. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>

                </div><!--tab içerik bitiş-->

                <div class="tab-content" data-tab="3"><!--tab içerik başlangıç-->

                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 3. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 3. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 3. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 3. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 3. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 3. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>


                </div><!--tab içerik bitiş-->

                <div class="tab-content" data-tab="4"><!--tab içerik başlangıç-->

                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 4. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 4. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 4. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 4. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 4. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 4. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>

                </div><!--tab içerik bitiş-->

                <div class="tab-content" data-tab="5"><!--tab içerik başlangıç-->

                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 5. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 5. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 5. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 5. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 5. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 5. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>

                </div><!--tab içerik bitiş-->

                <div class="tab-content" data-tab="6"><!--tab içerik başlangıç-->

                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 6. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 6. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 6. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 6. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 6. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>
                                <li class="mobilmenuicliste" ><img class="mobilmenulisteikonlar" src="assets/img/spor.png"><span><a  href="#"> 6. TAB MENÜSÜ</a></span></li>

                </div>
            <!--tab container bitiş-->

        </div><!--tablar bitiş-->
        </div>

        <!-- MOBİL MENÜ İÇ TABLAR BİTİŞ -->

        <!-- MOBİL MENÜ ALT BAR BAŞLANGIÇ -->
        <header style="" class="header">
  <div  class="container">
    <nav class="bottom-nav">
      <div class="bottom-nav-item active" style="width:0;">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
        <span id="hamburger" style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
          <span id="kapatici" style="font-size:30px; cursor:pointer" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/hesabim.png">
          <a>Hesabım</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/kurallar.png">
          <a>Kurallar</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/oranlar.png">
          <a>Oranlar</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-nav-item">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
          <img id="up" src="assets/img/mobilmenuikonlari/destek.png">
          <a>Destek</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

The css is

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1c1919; /* Black*/
  overflow-x:hidden;
  transition: 0s; /* no transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
```

and the JS is

```
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 100% */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "100%";
   document.getElementById("kapatici").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "none";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("kapatici").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: We can't help if we don't know what code you've written - please show us you HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code.

Comment: I've added the codes but this whole thing is something related with overflow-x:hidden; code

Comment: Do you have any ideas?